# Ошибка auth/argument-error при нажатии кнопки авторизации

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, auth

хочу использовать авторизацию через гугл аккаунт, используя firebase, но выдает ошибку auth/argument-error

```
firebase.ts
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  appId:"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  measurementId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
};
 
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {persistence: browserSessionPersistence, popupRedirectResolver: undefined});
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
 
export {auth,provider};
```

```
LoginButton.tsx
import {auth,provider} from './firebase'
export default function LoginButton(){
    const Auth = () => {
        signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then(data => data.user.getIdToken().then((token) => console.log(token)))
    }
 
 
    return (
        <button onClick={() => Auth()}>Войти</button>
    )
}
```